# How to recursively count a specific level members which contains NULL values within hierarchy

Tags: mdx, olap, cube

I've faced a misunderstanding while diving into the MDX. It's so different from regular SQL. I've processed my custom cube and developed a special calculated measure.

**What does it do?**

Well, It indicates whether it was no NULLs for all weeks within certain level(week, month, year) and count number of Shops which meet the condition.

My current hack:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Shop WBC]
AS SUM
([Shop].[Shop ID].[Shop ID].Members,
(IIF((Filter(Descendants([Time].[Week calendar], [Time].[Week calendar].[Week]),
[Measures].[Sales] IS NULL).Count) > 0, NULL, 1))
)
```

My testing select:

```
SELECT 
([Time].[Week calendar].[Week]) ON ROWS, 
([Shop].[Geo].[Region].Members, [Measures].[Shop WBC]) ON COLUMNS
FROM [Testable]
WHERE [Time].[Week].&[201301]:[Time].[Week].&[201319]
```

It returns 1 only (not NULL) for every shop, thus sum of shops.

However it returns the same value for all weeks (1 only). Why did it fail? I guess I don't get how **Descendants** function works in this case or something else? What do I miss? Hope my explanation is not so unclear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you intended to say `(Filter(Descendants([Time].[Week calendar], [Time].[Week calendar].[Week]), [Measures].[Sales] IS NULL).Count`. I am not sure why you used `[Measures].[Sales]` as the second argument to `Filter`.

Comment: Indeed. Good catch, thanks. Unfortunately that doesn't affect the output. Edited the code.

Comment: Could you post the complete statement including SELECT, WHERE, FROM that you are using?

Comment: @FrankPl, sure, updated my former post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you wrote your query, the weeks on the row are irrelevant to the result, as your `Filter` statement overwrites the context of the `Week calendar` hierarchy. You should write your query as

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Shop WBC]
AS SUM
([Shop].[Shop ID].[Shop ID].Members,
IIF((Filter(EXISTING [Time].[Week calendar].Members, [Measures].[Sales] IS NULL).Count > 0, NULL, 1)
)
SELECT 
([Time].[Week calendar].[Week]) ON ROWS, 
([Shop].[Geo].[Region].Members, [Measures].[Shop WBC]) ON COLUMNS
FROM [Testable]
WHERE [Time].[Week].&[201301]:[Time].[Week].&[201319]
```

Furthermore, in MDX, the `WHERE` clause is used much less frequently than in SQL. And, formally, it is illegal MDX to state the rows first. Proper MDX states the columns first and then the rows. However, Analysis Services is tolerant here. I would re-write the above query as

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Shop WBC]
    AS SUM(
    [Shop].[Shop ID].[Shop ID].Members,
    IIF((Filter(EXISTING [Time].[Week calendar].Members, [Measures].[Sales] IS NULL).Count > 0, NULL, 1)
    )
SELECT 
    [Shop].[Geo].[Region].Members
    * { [Measures].[Shop WBC] }
ON COLUMNS,
    [Time].[Week calendar].&[201301] : [Time].[Week calendar].&[201319]
ON ROWS
FROM [Testable]
```

Comment: Thanks for your job and time! But I've already written something like above before. Nevertheless I want it work with all levels (month, year, etc). That's why I used **Descendants** and **Filter**, and [Time].[Week calendar].CurrentMember is useless in this case. :(

Comment: @Kedny88 You mean "with all levels" on the rows - or "with all levels" for the measure definition?

Comment: Well, I want to get the set for specific level (week in my case). For week level it will get one member, but for month level it returns 4 members. I have to check whether the set contains any Null within and return Null if it's true. In case the set has no empty values for [Measures].[Sales] it returns 1. Then to sum their number. Does it make more sense to you?

Comment: @Kedny88 I edited my answer to use `EXISTING` which checks the context, but does not overwrite it.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, it's slow, but works. Is there any optimization about it?

Comment: @Kedny88 An approach for optimization could be: Define two additional measures in the cube: One indicator measure being 0 or 1 - depending on the week value being null or not, and aggregated with `max` or `min`. And then another that uses sum as aggregation function and the calculation of which is overwritten somehow like `([Measures].[Shop WBC], Leaves(Shop)) = [Measures].[Week NULL Indicator]` in the calc script, as inspired by http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2005/02/13/performance-of-aggregating-data-from-lower-levels-in-mdx.aspx. But I currently do not have the time to detail this.